# How to Store the Data in Local storage?

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I want to keep the form data in the table after reloading or refreshing  the page And i want to transfer the same data to the next page  after submiting  and update in the second page .

Page1.html

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <form action="page2.html">
      <table id="productTable" class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-striped">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Edit</th>
            <th>Product Name</th>
            <th>Introduction Date</th>
            <th>File</th>
            <th> Gender</th>
            <th>Currency Symbol</th>
            <th>Role</th>
            <th>Delete</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
      </table>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="passvalues();" />
    </form>
  </div>
</div> --------> here the data is displayed after submiting the form

<input type="text" class="form-control" name='name' id="productname" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="introdate">
    Introduction Date
  </label>
  <input type="date" class="form-control" id="introdate" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="img">
    image
  </label>
  <input type="file" class="form-control" id="img" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="Job">
    Gender
  </label>
  <div>
    <input type="radio" value="Male" id="radio" name="rate" required />
    <label for="Male" value="Male"><span>Male</span></label>

    <input type="radio" value="Female" id="radio" name="rate" required />
    <label for="Female" value="Female"><span>Female</span></label>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="Status">
    Status
  </label>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" name='check' value="USD">
    <label for="USD"> USD</label><br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" name='check' value="Rupees">
    <label for="Rupees" value="Rupees"> Rupees</label><br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" name='check' value="Pound">
    <label for="Pound" value="Pound"> Pound</label><br><br>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="role">
    Role
  </label>
  <div>
    <select class="form-control" id="role">
      <option value="">Select role..</option>
      <option value="Supervisor">Supervisor</option>
      <option value="Agent">Agent</option>
    </select>
  </div> -----------> Here the form data is submitted
```

javaScript of the page 1

```
// Next id for adding a new Product
var nextId = 1;
// ID of Product currently editing
var activeId = 0;

function productDisplay(ctl) {
  var row = $(ctl).parents("tr");
  var cols = row.children("td");

  activeId = $($(cols[0]).children("button")[0]).data("id");
  $("#productname").val($(cols[1]).text());
  $("#introdate").val($(cols[2]).text());
  $("#img").val($(cols[3]).val());
  $("input[type='radio'][name='rate']:checked").val($(cols[4]).text());
  $("input[type='checkbox'][name='check']:checked").val($(cols[5]).text());
  $("#role").val($(cols[6]).text());

  // Change Update Button Text
  $("#updateButton").text("Update");
}

function productUpdate() {
  localStorage.setItem("tabledata", $("#productTable tbody").html());
  var tabledata = localStorage.getItem("tabledata");
  $("#productTable tbody").html(tabledata);-----------> here i wrote the local storage function when the add button is clicked

  if ($("#updateButton").text() == "Update") {
    productUpdateInTable(activeId);
  } else {
    productAddToTable();
  }

  // Clear form fields
  formClear();

  // Focus to product name field
  $("#productname").focus();
}

// Add product to <table>
function productAddToTable() {
  // First check if a <tbody> tag exists, add one if not
  if ($("#productTable tbody").length == 0) {
    $("#productTable").append("<tbody></tbody>");
  }

  // Append product to table
  $("#productTable tbody").append(productBuildTableRow(nextId));

  // Increment next ID to use
  nextId += 1;
}

// Update product in <table>
function productUpdateInTable(id) {
  // Find Product in <table>
  var row = $("#productTable button[data-id='" + id + "']").parents("tr")[0];

  // Add changed product to table
  $(row).after(productBuildTableRow(id));
  // Remove original product
  $(row).remove();

  // Clear form fields
  formClear();

  // Change Update Button Text
  $("#updateButton").text("Add");
}

// Build a <table> row of Product data
function productBuildTableRow(id) {
  var ret =
    "<tr>" +
    "<td>" +
    "<button type='button' " +
    "onclick='productDisplay(this);' " +
    "class='btn btn-default' " +
    "data-id='" +
    id +
    "'>" +
    "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit' />" +
    "</button>" +
    "</td>" +
    "<td>" +
    $("#productname").val() +
    "</td>" +
    "<td>" +
    $("#introdate").val() +
    "</td>" +
    "<td>" +
    $("#img").val() +
    "</td>" +
    "<td>" +
    $("input[type='radio'][name='rate']:checked").val() +
    "</td>" +
    "<td>" +
    $("input[type='checkbox'][name='check']:checked").val() +
    "</td>" +
    "<td>" +
    $("#role").val() +
    "</td>" +
    "<td>" +
    "<button type='button' " +
    "onclick='productDelete(this);' " +
    "class='btn btn-default' " +
    "data-id='" +
    id +
    "'>" +
    "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove' />" +
    "</button>" +
    "</td>" +
    "</tr>";

  return ret;
}

// Delete product from <table>
function productDelete(ctl) {
  $(ctl).parents("tr").remove();
}

// Clear form fields
function formClear() {
  $("#productname").val("");
  $("#introdate").val("");
  $("#img").val("");
  $("input[type='radio'][name='rate']:checked").val("");
  $("input[type='checkbox'][name='check']:checked").val("");
  $("#role").val("");
}

function passvalues() {
  var name = $("#productname").val("");
  localStorage.setItem("name", $("#productname").val());
  return false;
}

window.onbeforeunload = function () {
  localStorage.setItem("name", $("#productname").val());
  localStorage.setItem("date", $("#introdate").val());
  localStorage.setItem("image", $("#imge").val());
  localStorage.setItem(
    "radio",
    $("input[type='radio'][name='rate']:checked").val()
  );
  localStorage.setItem(
    "check",
    $("input[type='checkbox'][name='check']:checked").val()
  );
  localStorage.setItem("role", $("#role").val());
  // ...
};
```

And in Page2.html

```
<body>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <table id="productTable" class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-striped">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Product Name</th>
            <td><span id="result"></span></td>
            <th>Introduction Date</th>
            <th>File</th>
            <th> Gender</th>
            <th>Currency Symbol</th>
            <th>Role</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script>
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("name");
    -- -- -- > trying to get the data from page 1 to page
  </script>
</body>
```

I want to show the data in table after reloading a page or refreshing in it . And After Submitting it Those data should load in the page2.html

Comment: So where specifically are you having problems and or errors?

Comment: I am not able to load the data in the table there were no errors in the console too

Comment: @GamingWithShadyWolf: "Not able" how, exactly?  When you use your browser's debugging tools to browser the local storage, is the value you expect saved?  In your browser's script debugger have you confirmed that the `localStorage.setItem` function is being invoked when you expect and storing the value you expect?  If so, what happens when you debug the second page?  Does `localStorage.getItem` return the value you expect?  When you debug, what specifically fails?

Comment: the Function triggers when i click the add button but the localstorage function is int working and the data are not storred in the browser debugging tool.

Comment: @GamingWithShadyWolf: You're going to need to be more specific.  First, reduce the problem to a [mcve] to demonstrate specifically what you're trying to accomplish.  When you debug (using the browser's script debugger to step through the code as it executes) which specific operation produces an unexpected result?  Where specifically do you call `localStorage.setItem` in which it doesn't save a value?  What specific runtime value do you *observe* that you're trying to save?  Simply saying that "local storage isn't working" is a non-starter.  Unless your browser is broken, it works fine.

Answer (score 3):

Use The `setItem()` method of the `Storage` interface.

Have a look at the MDN Documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) - it explains `localStorage` usage much more in-depth.

Comment: Already used the Set Item